# define ordinal data type in rapidminer

Tags: data-mining, rapidminer

I want to know how can I define ordinal data type for my attributes in rapid miner?
for example I have blood pressure attribute with three values (High,Normal,low) or cholesterol with high and normal values and some other attributes like this. should I set integer data type for these attributes?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You'd better replace `text` with `integer`, `integer` would be more convenient when you apply some algorithms.